# ¿Qué significa "su la" cuando las dos palabras se usan juntas?

Tags: artículos

No entiendo por qué «su la» aparece en la frase de abajo.  Entendería la frase si uno u otro se hubiera usado solo, pero ¿por qué ambos?

> La mamá espera en el carro, observando *su la* antigua casa con techo a dos aguas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como mucho, históricamente era (y hoy día es con artículos indefinidos en ciertas regiones) válido decir ***la su*** antigua casa, pero en orden *su la* no lo es.

En este caso, es sencillamente un error.

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta.  Para estar seguro, acabo de verificar el orden y no lo cambié cuando lo copié.  Me decepciona que haya un error en la frase original porque es de un libro para niños.

Comment: @hcbowman será un error.  Como por sí solo tanto *su* como *la* casa es válido, sin duda alguien empezó escribiendo el primero, y luego quiso cambiarlo al segundo (o al revés) sin borrar el primero.